# how to create device independent layout in android using weight attribute

Tags: android, android-layout

i want to create the Login layout like given below..
with using  weight attribute..

[image]

it should be device independent..
means in all android device it should look same

Comment: It seems the case where 9 patches come handy. And backgrounds (for the lower part). Really, I think it can be done with a (lighter) RelativeLayout, no weights

Comment: i am using weight attribute

Answer (score 1):

Split main container in 2 parts for Login part set weight 2, bottom part as 1, then add containers with width and height = match_parent and first part done, then set padding for containers, those containers itself can be relative nested in linear containers so it will be easier to compose Login part.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout >
            Your views here
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout >
            Your views here
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```